# Perl ping with tcp protocol

Tags: perl, networking, tcp, ping, icmp

I am using the perl module Net::Ping to ping a set of remote hosts. I am using the default protocol, i.e. the tcp one. I am unable to ping 1 particular remote machine using this protocol.

Unix ping works fine, and so does the icmp protocol.

What could be the reason of this failure? Is there any setting I need to do on the host?

Comment: Probably firewall settings. ping-ish stuff is done via udp and icmp. tcp is overkill for that purpose, so they might block it, assuming the client is up to no good.

Comment: It is not pingable via UDP also. I don't really think there are any firewall settings enabled on the machine.

Comment: Actually, you were right! Firewall enabled on the machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably firewall settings. ping-ish stuff is done via udp and icmp. tcp is overkill for that purpose, so they might block it, assuming the client is up to no good.